# VSCode debugger can not import queue due to shadowing

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

When I try to run any python code in debug mode using VScode, I got an error message saying:

```
42737 -- /home/<username>/Desktop/development/bopi/experiment_handler.py .vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/<username>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from debugpy.server import cli
  File "/home/<username>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd  # noqa
  File "/home/<username>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/_vendored/force_pydevd.py", line 37, in <module>
    pydevd_constants = import_module('_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/<username>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_constants.py", line 362, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle._pydev_saved_modules import thread, threading
  File "/home/<username>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 97, in <module>
    import queue as _queue;    verify_shadowed.check(_queue, ['Queue', 'LifoQueue', 'Empty', 'Full', 'deque'])
  File "/home/<username>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 75, in check
    raise DebuggerInitializationError(msg)
_pydev_bundle._pydev_saved_modules.DebuggerInitializationError: It was not possible to initialize the debugger due to a module name conflict.

i.e.: the module "queue" could not be imported because it is shadowed by:
/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queue/__init__.pyc
Please rename this file/folder so that the original module from the standard library can be imported.
```

Deleting the **init**.pyc and **init**.py resulting with an error message about missing queue import.

Comment: It's time to upgrade! Python 2.7 is EoL. I bet that the error will go away as well.

Comment: It's time to abandon VSCode! If it not works with 2.7, back to IDLE or Aptana. Better than to be forced to change hundreds of scripts in 2.7 to 3.6, each print, each encoding...arrgh!

Comment: While it is definitely time to upgrade, some of us have to maintain legacy code bases where it is not within our power to make that decision.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Downgrading my Python extension in Visual Studio Code to `v2022.2.1924087327` worked for me.

Elevating [@Onur Berk's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709229/vscode-debugger-can-not-import-queue-due-to-shadowing/71711905#comment126743454_71711905) as part of the answer:

> Its is very easy to downgrade the python extension, just click 'extensions' and find the Python extension and select it. Rather than clicking 'uninstall' click the arrow next to it, this will give you an option to install another version

Comment: Its is very easy to downgrade the python extension, just click 'extensions' and find the Python extension and select it. Rather than clicking 'uninstall' click the arrow next to it, this will give you an option to install another version.

Comment: I will add that for this to work, I had to restart VS Code also.

Comment: this solution helped me also! Thanks a lot, but mb you know if it will be resolved in vscode latest version?